# Android: Make scrollable TextView always focus first line?

Tags: android, textview

How to make the scrollable textview always focus on the first line/focus top?

Problem: When I scroll the textview to the third line at the first page,it will assume there are also three lines of text in the second page, causing the text "disappears" when my second page has only one line of text.

`txtCaptions.scrollTo(0,txtCaptions.getLayout().getLineTop(0));` doesn't work for me.

Comment: use this dear..,

txtCaptions.setMovementMethod(null);
txtCaptions.setFocusable(false);

Comment: @KURUMADDALIANURAG thanks for your quick reply, but I still need my `txtCaptions` to be scrollable, so I can't use `setMovementMethod(null)` in my case. I also tried a single `setFocusable(false);` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi dear,
           sorry for delay, if u want to make your textview scrollable use like this in layout properties

android:maxLines="2"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"

and use this code programatically 

txtCaptions.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());